# Unable to figure out the error in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, keyerror

I get the below error when I try to run a `python` code. I don't have the visibility of the full code but is there a way to understand what is causing the below issue from the error message that is thrown?

Is it related to any module error or any runtime error or any directions to look into? Apologies for not sharing the code as I don't have access to it but just trying to understand. Not sure if it's related to `pandas`

Python version - 3.8

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testscript.py", line 441, in <module>
    create_html_table(report_dict_list, env) #necessary?
  File "testscript.py", line 205, in create_html_table
    dfs = df.sort_values(['UserID', 'Location', 'AwsEnv', 'Host', 'Address', 'Status', 'State', 'InstanceName', 'Type', 'NoofDays', 'StackName'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 311, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 6242, in sort_values
    keys = [self._get_label_or_level_values(x, axis=axis) for x in by]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 6242, in <listcomp>
    keys = [self._get_label_or_level_values(x, axis=axis) for x in by]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1779, in _get_label_or_level_values
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'UserID'
```

Comment: Looks like one of the keys in sort values doesn't exist in the dataframe.

Comment: It would have told you which key, but you didn't include the entire traceback.

Comment: oh right, my bad. Updated the trace now. `KeyError: 'UserID'`

Comment: What is the output of `print(df.columns)`?

Comment: thanks everyone, i was able to figure out the issue onto why there was no UserID present. creating one UserID in that region worked.

Answer (score 0):

The code is attempting to access a key called 'UserID' and it does not exist in the pandas DataFrame.

It is possible that the code expects a column with the 'UserID' value in some sort of data file or configuration file that it reads.

Based on the traceback I can't tell where it's looking. Other than it may be some sort of html table or report.

Comment: thanks everyone, i was able to figure out the issue onto why there was no UserID present. creating one UserID in that region worked.